# mathematical puzzle on binary string

Tags: string, algorithm

I have been given  a binary string of length n and i need to find the minimum numbers of operations to perform such that  string does not contain more than k consecutive equal characters.

Only kind of operation I am  allowed to perform is to flip any ith character of the string. flipping a character means changing a '1' to '0' or a '0' to '1'.

for example:

if n = 4 , k =  1 and string = 1001

then Answer:

string = 1010 and minimum operations = 2

I need to also find the new string.

can anyone tell me an efficient algorithm for solving problem considering n <=10^5

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: looks like dynamic prog...

Comment: @dummycpp if input string is 1000 and k=1 , final string is ?

Comment: final string = 1010 and operation =  1

Comment: edit the question , with the explanation u gave in comment

Comment: final string is not 110011001 as the operations are more for this string than for 101001100,, u will need 4 operation to convert 111001100 to 110011001 and u will need 1 operation to convert 111001100 to 101001100

Comment: then how solution of string 1000 and k =1 is 1010 and 1 ? it shud be not possible

Comment: u have to just to follow the condition  " new string should not contain more than k consecutive equal characters." and correspondingly find minimum number of operations

Answer (score 3):

There's one way:

```
if k>1:
    if k+1 matching characters are found:
        if a[k+1]==a[k+2]:
            flip a[k+1]
        else if a[k+1]!=a[k+2]:
            flip a[k]
```

for k=1 you can do it!
Here flipping means from 1 to 0 and vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

For k=1 there are only two possible output strings - the one beginning with 0 and the one beginning with 1. You can check which of them is closer to the input string.

For larger k, you can just look at every sequence of k+1 identical characters, and fix it internally - without changing the characters at either end. For a sequence of k' > k  you would need floor(k'/(k+1)) flips. It should not be hard to show that this is optimal.

Running time is linear and extra space is constant.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases:

```
1)For k>1
   We have 2 possibilities.
     a)one that is starting with 0:
       eg:0101010101
     b)one that is starrting with 1
       eg:10101010.....
We should now calculate the distance(the number of different elements between the 2 strings)for each possiblity.Then the ans will be the one that has minimum changes.
```

2)for k>1

```
    res2=0;res1=1;
    c1=A[i];//it represents the last elemnet
    i=1;
    while(A[i]!='\0'){
      if(A[i]==c1){
        res1++;//the no of consecutive elements
           if(res1>k){
               if(A[i]==A[i+1])
                  flip(i);//it flips the ith element
                else
                   flip(i-1);
                res2++;//it counts the no of changes
                res1=1;
            }            
       }
       else
         res1=1;

      c1=A[i];
      i++;
    }
```